# How to fix column in bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

So this code block doesnt work properly. Its meant to show these two columns side by side but just doesnt work. Please help.

[image: Problem shown in the following pic]

I was watching a tutorial and this was meant to work. I also crosschecked with the documentation but it still didnt work.

```html
<section id="feature-one">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="feature-content">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <a href="#"><img src="../Mywebsite/images/Umass logo.png" alt="Umass Logo" width="100%" height="200px"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-1">
          <h3> Click on the Logo to view my UMass Experience </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The columns are meant to be side by side but show to be one on top of the other.

Comment: are you in sm-mode? do col-md-* help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't wrap `.col` tags with `<div class="feature-content">`. It breaks the Bootstrap CSS.

If you need some features of `feature-content` class, add it to the `row` tag.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="feature-one">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row feature-content">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <a href="#"><img src="../Mywebsite/images/Umass logo.png" alt="Umass Logo" width="100%" height="200px"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-1">
        <h3> Click on the Logo to view my UMass Experience </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```